# Find if binary tree has odd number of nodes

Tags: java

I have written code to find if a binary tree has an odd number of nodes. But I think I am missing out some edge cases here. This is not returning correct output. I have trued searching but have not found any hints. Can someone please take a look at my code and guide me?

```
public boolean oddNumber(Node root) {
        if(root==null)
            return false;
        if ((root.left!=null && root.right!=null) )
            return true;
        else
            return oddNumber(root.left) || oddNumber(root.right );
    }
```

Comment: Is the tree guaranteed to be balanced?

Comment: The logic is incorrect. You'll have to keep count of the nodes somewhere.

Comment: can I do without keeping note of the node count? I think we can

Comment: For a generic [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) with no further constraints, I don't see how.

Comment: Even simpler: `public boolean oddNumber(Node root){return root==null ? false : oddNumber(root.left)==oddNumber(root.right);}`

Answer (score 2):

solution:

```
public boolean isOdd(Node root) {
        if(root==null)
            return false;
        return (isOdd(root.left)==isOdd(root.right));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static boolean hasOddNodeCount(int nodeCount){
    return ((nodeCount % 2) != 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Idea is to NOT use nodeCount.